# How can I extend an existing package / library in Dart?

Tags: dart

How can I extend an existing package / library in Dart?

e.g.

```
import 'package:eventify/eventify.dart';

extend EventEmitter { // <- object from package
  once() { 
    // my code here
  }
}

void main() {
  EventEmitter().once(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from dart 2.6 (which is currently in dev)

[feature specification example](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/static-extension-methods/feature-specification.md#examples)

For example:

```
extension MyEmitter on EventEmitter {
  once() {
    // code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, not possible yet, although it has been proposed for a future Dart release.